# Prepopulate non-model form attribute when instantiating in Django

Tags: django

I want to set a minimum value for a DecimalField attribute on a form at the time when I instantiate it in the view. And I want to get that minimum value from an object I gather from the database. I made it (sort of) work by manually putting in the html form in the template, but want to refactor it to use the form class because I can do more useful things with data in the view than I can in the template.

Based on my reading of other questions and docs, I can't set attributes with the `.initial` argument. I thought likely I need to override the `__init__` method on the form, but I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this right and it makes no sense syntactically. Here's what I have tried:

```
class BidForm(forms.Form):
    bid = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    listing_bid = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, min_bid, listing_pk, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bid'].min = min_bid
        self.fields['listing_bid'] = listing_pk
```

My idea is to have this form take a `min_bid` and a `listing_pk`, and fill the "min" attribute on the html input with whatever is in the `min_bid` variable. I want to put the `listing_pk` that's passed in as the value in a hidden field called "listing_bid". If it helps clarify, I'm trying to generate html equivalent to:

```
<input type="number" name="bid" min="{{ listing.current_bid }}">
<input type="hidden" name="listing_bid" value="{{ listing.pk }}">
```

In the view, I'd like to say something like:

```
form = BidForm(min_bid=foo, listing_bid=bar)
```

Then pass that into the template context for rendering.

Does this make sense? I've found some discussion of it in the context of ModelForms but can't wrap my head around how to do this with regular forms.

Edit: for future reference, here is what worked for me. I deleted the bid attribute on the form because there's no case where I would want to init it without supplying a `min_bid`:

```
class BidForm(forms.Form):
    listing_bid = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, min_bid, listing_pk, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bid'] = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, min_value=min_bid)
        self.fields['listing_bid'].initial = listing_pk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `.initial` attribute:

```
class BidForm(forms.Form):
    bid = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    listing_bid = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, min_bid, listing_pk, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bid'].min_value = min_bid
        self.fields['listing_bid'].intial = listing_pk
```

Comment: Ah, got it - that will fill the listing_bid with whatever is in listing_pk, but what about the attribute on the bid field? Is that going to function with this syntax? When I instantiate it in the view, the html generated doesn't include the "min" attribute I'm looking for. It's just: <input type="number" name="bid" step="0.01" required="" id="id_bid">

Comment: @testingtesting: ah, but the min value is specified with `.min_value`.

Comment: This actually didn't work. I ended up getting it working by setting the bid field equal to a new DecimalField: `self.fields['bid'] = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, min_value=min_bid)` I then deleted the declaration of the bid variable outside the `__init__` (`bid = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)`) but it worked the same whether it was in there or not.